After upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 my login screen is completely broken
After upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 my login screen is completely broken, wrong fonts, pop-ups overlap each other and are not hidden, not images, but...
All working, I can successfully login.
I already tried:

Clear GNOME configs (rm -rf ~/.gnome* ~/.gconf* ~/.metacity ~/.cache ~/.dbus ~/.dmrc ~/.mission-control ~/.thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/*)
Reset dconf (dconf reset -f /org/gnome/). Later I reset all dconf root, but I had no luck.
Clear old GNOME extensions (rm -rf ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions)
Try https://askubuntu.com/a/1525026/1958068 - no luck
Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/777843 - i dont have problems with gdm, but i`m trying too, and no luck
DM logs from sudo systemctl status display-manager:

systemd[1]: Starting gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager...
systemd[1]: Started gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager.
gdm-launch-environment][1419]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=110) by (uid=0)
gdm-password][1994]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
gdm-password][1994]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
gdm-password][1994]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user helium(uid=1001) by helium(uid=0)
gdm3[3702]: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic
gdm3[3798]: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic
gdm3[1413]: Gdm: Child process -1445 was already dead.
gdm3[4099]: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic

Broken panel in login screen:

I`m attach only panel in login screen, but ALL login screen graphics and menus are broken, all widgets, etc.
After successfully logging in, my workspace is fine. There are no more bugs, only the login screen is broken.

This question is similar to: How to fix broken 24.04.1 LTS upgrade which is missing necessary software?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You might like to try one of the solutions at this location. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746729/ubuntu-fails-to-boot-because-of-gdm-problem

I m try this solutions, not helped

Can you append to your question the result of the following command. 'systemctl status display-manager'

@david no nvidia drivers found in logs, but in drivers window, no nvidia drivers available (GF108M [GeForce GT 620M/630M/635M/640M LE]). And after login no screen bugs (until I log out)

I didn't realise you were using nvidia drivers. I suspect you need to re-install them. I think the gdm drivers are built  separately from the main graphics drives.
